# fineuploader combined with edit page

Tags: php, jquery, html, fine-uploader

I am using fineuploader in combination with php. I use it to add images to a blogpost. When a new post is added the information is stored in a database. There is also an edit page for each post. On this edit page the images that belong to that post should be editable trough fineuploader.

Does anyone know if there is a feature for this? If there is any way to parse the existing images into the fineuploader?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  What, specifically, do you want to do with these images?  Once the images are server-side, Fine Uploader's job is over, for the most part.

Comment: I want to be able to remove these images using fineuploader

Answer (score 0):

Fine Uploader is not a file manager, it is a cross-browser upload library.  You can enable the [delete file feature](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/01/delete-uploaded-file-in-33.html) and ask Fine Uploader to send a DELETE request for files that have been uploaded during the current Fine Uploader session.  If you want to delete files that have been uploaded from a previous instance of Fine Uploader, you will need to account for this in your web app with a simple ajax call to your server that orders removal of these files.